# Windows 10, Wamp and Google Drive as www or alias (permissions)

Tags: wamp, windows-10

I'm trying to set up an alias for wamp on Windows 10 that should point to a folder in my Google Drive and I just can't get it to work. I know there is some issue with the Drive folder's permission that causes Wamp to caugh up but all the answers I found were for Windows 8 - and guess what? It looks like M$ changed the permission dialog and I can't find the correct settings/options.

For completeness, here's my conf file in wamp/alias
(%gdrivef% is the path to my Google Drive with forward slashes (thus the 'f'))

```
Alias /pocketr/ "%gdrivef%" 

<Directory "%gdrivef%">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Help, anyone?

Comment: What is `%gdrivef%` and what have `M$` got to do with Google Drive?

Comment: Heh see the paragraph before the codeblock :)

Comment: Do you see anything in the Apache documentation that makes you think it will expand something like that into a directory it can make any use of [or is the manual something new to you](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)

Comment: Oh also you are using Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4 syntax and that often confuses Apache 2.4. Get rid of `Order allow,deny
    Allow from all` and just use `Require all granted` Assuming you actually want to allow the universe to access your alias

Comment: %gdrivef% is an environ variable, it should work right? It's the OS that should handle that part? (I'm not so sure all of a sudden...). I'll remove the old stuff but the weird part is that it does work on my laptop that I upgraded from Win7 to 10 but this pc doesn't (fresh install win 10). MS changed the OS dialog for folder permissions, you can't change it via G Drive settings for as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Oh great it all turns out to be caused by spaces in the Google Drive folder name.. I thought I (tried to) solve(d) that by mapping it to a drive folder (x:) but that didn't work either.. I just assumed that this proved it wasn't the issue.

Soooo: *don't* use spaces in folder names when you want Wamp to work.

Why does Google install Drive in a folder with spaces anyway? They should know that using spaces in file/folder names are a death sin.

Oh well. Another problem solved.